# Change the sound of the message boxes in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, audio, messagebox

i have a question, Is it possible to change the sound of the message boxes in tkinter? I don't want it to be the windows sounds but a custom one. Thanks!!!

Comment: No, this is an OS setting rather than something that can be configured from tkinter.

Comment: Ok ok ... Thanks for your comment !!!